# $T$ an irreducible linear operator $\Longleftrightarrow T$ cyclic and $\mu_T(x)$ irreducible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Definitions: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $T$ an operator on $V$. Let $\mu_{T,v}(x)$ denote the minimal polynomial of $T$ with respect to $T$ $($ i.e. the unique monic generator of $\text{ann}(T,v)= \{f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]:f(T)(v)=0 \})$ and let $\mu_T(x)$ denote the unique monic polynomial of least degree in $\text{ann}(T)=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]:f(T)(v)=0 \text{ for every } v \in V \}.$

I'm reading through my textbooking trying to understand the following theorem:

> Theorem. $T$ is an irreducible operator (No non-trivial $T$-invariant subspace) $\Longleftrightarrow T$ is cyclic (there is a $v \in V$ such that $\langle T,v \rangle = V)$ and $\mu_T(x)$ is irreducible.

For the $(\Leftarrow)$ part of the theorem (sketch), assume $V = \langle T,v \rangle$, let $w \in V, w \ne 0$ and then show $\mu_{T,w}(x)=\mu_{T}(x) = \mu_{T,v}(x)$. Then the dimension of the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $w$, $\dim \langle T,w \rangle=\{f(T)(w):f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x] \}$ is equal to $\dim \langle T,v \rangle = \dim V$. From this we conclude that $V$ contains no non-trivial $T$-invariant subspace which proves $T$ irreducible.

Question $1$: Why does $\dim \langle T,w \rangle = \dim V = \dim \langle T,v \rangle$ imply that $V$ contains no non-trivial $T$-invariant subspace? It seems that we have proved that every $T$-cyclic subspace $\langle T,v \rangle$ of $V$ has the same dimension as $V$, but I am not clear why this implies that there are no non-trivial $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$. I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that the $T$-cyclic subspaces of $V$ are $T$-invariant.

> Corollary. Let $V$ be a vector space, $T$ an operator on $V$, and $v \in V$ such that $\mu_{T,v}(x)$ is irreducible. Let $W$ be a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$. Then either $\langle T,v \rangle \subset W$ or $\langle T,v \rangle \cap W = \{0\}.$

Question $2$. How does this corollary follow?

Comment: What is your textbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: Let $W \neq 0$ be a $T$-invariant subspace. Choose $0 \neq w \in W$ and consider the $T$-invariant subspace $\left<T, w \right>$. Since $\left< T, w \right> \subseteq W$ and $\dim \left< T, w \right> = \dim V$, we must have $\dim W = \dim V$ so $W = V$.

Question 2: The operator $T|_{\left< T, v \right>}$ is cyclic and so, by the theorem, $T|_{\left< T, v \right>}$ does not have non-trivial invariant subspaces. Since the intersection of $T$-invariant subspaces is $T$-invariant and $W \cap \left< T, v \right> \subseteq \left< T, v \right>$, we must have $W \cap \left<T, v \right> = \{ 0 \}$ or $W \cap \left< T, v \right> = \left< T, v \right>$ which implies that $\left< T, v \right> \subseteq W$.